# A question on the name of a property

Tags: lo.logic, terminology

What is the name of the following property of a system $T$?

> If $\vdash_{T}\exists x F(x)$ then 
>   there is a term $a$ such that $\vdash_{T} F(a)$

If I recall correctly Heyting Arithmetics has the property, and 
clearly also Omega Logic has it. 
Are there other important examples?

Comment: This is called the existence property.

Comment: Thanks. Consequently, the following Wikipedia article becomes useful:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_and_existence_properties

Comment: You might also be interested in Herbrand logic. This is a modified semantics for first-order logic in which the underlying set of a model is always the set of terms in the language. Hence if $M\models \exists x\,\varphi(x)$, then $M \models \varphi(a)$ for some term $a$.

Comment: If you require this property only for closed formulas of the form $\exists x\, F(x)$, then I would call $T$ a _Henkin theory_.

Comment: @Goldstern Is that language use connected with Henkin Models? Is it standard, or common, language use?

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal Rather than quoting my own book I can point to Shoenfield's book (4.2, page 45), which uses this notation. (But requires constants, not just any terms.)  Also Hinman (Fundamentals of Math.Logic 3.1, page 196) calls a complete theory "Henkin complete" if there are "Henkin witnesses" for every closed existential formula.  This concept is used for Henkin's proof of Gödel's completeness theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "[$T$ has witnesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witness_(mathematics))"?